# Access Javascript Array Value Using Outputfield as key VF

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Have a visualforce page with that is generated from a custom button on the account. On this page, we have some JS that contains an array. I am trying to take the value of the below field from the account:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!account.lastname}" id="lastname" />
```

And on a button click, find this value as a key and return the value from the array.

```
function myfunction(){
window.alert(array["{!account.lastname}"])}
```

I am receiving "undefined" in the alert. If I just alert the outputfield it will display it, but not access it from the array. Thanks.

Comment: What does the javascript array build look like? is the array really called "array" ?

Comment: `var minitialList = {
    ip: 61,
    b: 62,
    c: 63,
    d: 64,
    e: 65,
    f: 66,
    g: 67,
    h: 68,
    i: 69,
    j: 70,
    k: 71,
    l: 72,
    m: 73,
    n: 74,
    o: 75,
    p: 76,
    q: 77,
    r: 78,
    s: 82,
    t: 83,
    u: 84,
    v: 85,
    w: 86,
    x: 87,
    y: 88,
    z: 89,
    NONE: 00
}`

Comment: then it looks like your javascript should be something like:
`window.alert(minitialList["{!account.lastname}"]` and it will only return something if the account lastname is "ip" or "b" or something. Your array keys are letters. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thats exactly what I have above in the original question that is returning undefined and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to take the value of the field on the account and match it against the array, returning the associated number per that field/letter.

Comment: what's the Account.LastName ? and btw in the question you have this: `window.alert(array["{!account.lastname}"])` note it says `array` not `minitialList`

Comment: In testing this the account last name is "Ip" (to test a value in the array). The field itself is the last name field from the person account.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. Ip is not ip

Comment: That was it...always the simplest things, thanks a bunch!